# Magento 2 : Restrict payment method by country not working

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I am facing issue related payment method show for the specific country using Magento 2.2.6. Below are the steps followed by me

> 1. Set "Payment from Applicable Countries" to Specific Countries and a select couple of countries.
> 2. On Frontend - open checkout and select any allowed country and click NEXT. It will show desired payment methods in the next step.
> 3. Go back to Step #1 and select any other country which doesn't allow Check and Money Order and click NEXT.
> 4. It will still show Check and Money Order though it is set to NO for the selected country.

This issue is also available on git hub community but I didn't find any solution. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10234

Please help me to solve this default Magento 2 issue.

Comment: I think the issue will be resolved if you update to the latest Magento version

Comment: this issue is coming in Magento 2.3 also

Comment: any update on this issue. I didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has been fixed or not or in what terms it can be reproduced but I found it and had some problems with it in version 2.3.5. I tracked the code down to this file:

vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Checks/CanUseForCountry/CountryProvider.php

For whatever reason it seems that (on a multi store at least) the billing address country always gets to be NULL and goes back to the default country set in configurations. I don't exactly know why it gets null on billing address country but I wrote a workaround to always get the shipping address country (that seems to always be the right one).

I made a plugin with an after for the method getCountry() and replaced this:

```
    $address = $quote->getBillingAddress() ? : $quote->getShippingAddress();
```

with this:

```
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
```

Now I don't have any problems. I really don't know where this bug comes from and why that billing country is always NULL but at least now it works as intended. Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked for me too !!